# Упорядочить список

Tags: c, строки, сортировка, структуры

Не получается отсортировать список в соответствии с упорядочением:

```
1 вратари;
2 защитники;
3 полузащитники;
4 нападающие;
```

Сортировать нужно методом минимума-максимума.
Есть структура

```
struct football {
    char surname[N];
    char nation[N];
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
    char amplua[N];
    char country[N];
} player[11];
```

В файле в столбце `amplua` записаны указанные категории.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<locale.h>
#define N 50

 struct football {
    char surname[N];
    char nation[N];
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
    char amplua[N];
    char country[N];
}player[11],flag;


int main () {
    int i=0, max, index;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    FILE* f;
    struct football *record = malloc(sizeof(struct football));
    if ((f = fopen("record.txt", "r"))==NULL) 
    {
            printf("error");
        }
    else {

        while (!feof(f))
        {
            fscanf(f,"%s", player[i].surname);
            fscanf(f,"%s", &player[i].nation);
            fscanf(f,"%d", &player[i].age);
            fscanf(f,"%d", &player[i].height);
            fscanf(f,"%d", &player[i].weight);
            fscanf(f,"%s", &player[i].amplua);
            fscanf(f,"%s", &player[i].country);
            i++;
        }
        printf("+----------+-----------+----+-----+----+--------------+-----------+\n");
        printf("| Фамилия  |Гражданство|Возр| Рост| Вес|  Амплуа      |Где играет |\n");
        printf("+----------+-----------+----+-----+----+--------------+-----------+\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            printf("|%9s | %9s | %2d | %3d | %2d | %12s | %9s |\n", player[i].surname, player[i].nation, player[i].age, player[i].height, player[i].weight, player[i].amplua, player[i].country);

        }
        printf("+----------+-----------+----+-----+----+--------------+-----------+\n");

        max = player[0].height;
        index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<11; i++)
        {   
            if (V(player[i].amplua) &&(max<player[i].height))
            {
                max = player[i].height;
                index = i;
            }

        }

        printf("\nСамый высокий вратарь - %s;\n", player[index].surname);
        printf("Футболисты , которые играют не в своей стране:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            if (!Nation(player[i].nation,player[i].country))
            {
                printf("-%s;\n", player[i].surname);
            }
        }for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            if (Sort())
                printf("|%9s | %9s | %2d | %3d | %2d | %12s | %9s |\n", player[i].surname, player[i].nation, player[i].age, player[i].height, player[i].weight, player[i].amplua, player[i].country);
        }
    }
    free(record);
    fclose(f);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

int V(char amplua[]) {
    int i;
    char v[] = "вратарь";
    if (strlen(amplua) != strlen(v))
        return 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(amplua); i++)
        if (amplua[i] != v[i])
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int Nation(char nation[],char county[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        if (nation[i] != county[i])

    return 0;
}

int Vr(char amplua[]) {
    int i;
    char v[] = "вратарь";

    if (strlen(amplua) != strlen(v))
        return 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(amplua); i++)
        if (amplua[i] != v[i]) 

    return 0;

}

int Z(char amplua[]) {
    int i;
    char z[] = "защитник";
    if (strlen(amplua) != strlen(z))
        return 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(amplua); i++)
        if (amplua[i] != z[i])

    return 0;
    amplua[i] = 2;
}

int PZ(char amplua[]) {
    int i;
    char p[] = "полузащитник";
    if (strlen(amplua) != strlen(p))
        return 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(amplua); i++)
        if (amplua[i] != p[i])

    return 0;
amplua[i] = 3;
}

int NP(char amplua[]) {
    int i;
    char n[] = "нападающий";
    if (strlen(amplua) != strlen(n))
        return 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(amplua); i++)
        if (amplua[i] != n[i])

    return 0;
 amplua[i] = 4;
}

int Sort() {
    int i = 0;
    Vr(player[i].amplua);
    Z(player[i].amplua);
    PZ(player[i].amplua);
    NP(player[i].amplua);
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        int min = player[i].amplua;
        int minIndex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 11; j++) {
            if (player[i].amplua < min) {
                min = player[j].amplua;
                minIndex = j;

                flag = player[i];
                player[i] = player[minIndex];
                player[minIndex] = flag;
            }
        }
        printf("|%9s | %9s | %2d | %3d | %2d | %12s | %9s |\n", player[i].surname, player[i].nation, player[i].age, player[i].height, player[i].weight, player[i].amplua, player[i].country);

    }

}
```

Пыталась присвоить числа ,чтоб как то упорядочило. Ничего не сортирует. И этот метод не могу найти.

Comment: Желательно убрать из кода все, что не относится к теме. Спрашиваете про min-max sorting, а в коде еще и чтение из файла, поиск самого высокого вратаря и т.п.

Comment: У вас в коде несколько мест, где у `if` пропущено тело, например в `Nation()`. Кроме того, в `Z()` и еще кое-где есть код после `return`, который никогда не будет выполнен. Еще, в начале `Sort()` вызовы `Vr`, `Z`, `PZ`, `NP` ничего не делают. Еще, хотя это и не относится к сортировке, `while (!feof(f))` делает не то, что вы думаете, подробнее [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Так ,а что делать с сортировкой ? Как  сортировать этим методом ?

Comment: Вот тут кажется есть код: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41667225/selection-sort-from-both-ends-with-min-and-max

Comment: Не проще ли использовать сортировку подсчётом?
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: @SOCIOPATH В идеале вообще нужно брать `qsort()`. Что-то мне подсказывает, что это домашнее задание, и метод выбрать нельзя...